# How do I read a single character from a Scanner?

Tags: java, char, character

I have a list of Characters and I want to add each character to the list as a user enters them (keyboard is a Scanner). I've tried two different approaches, neither works:

```
char temp = keyboard.nextByte();
charList.add(temp);
```

or

```
charList.add(keyboard.nextBye();
```

So how would I go about this?

Comment: you could use `nextLine` and loop over each char of the string and insret it into the list.

Comment: Title is misleading.  This has nothing to do with an ArrayList.  It should be “How do I read a single character from a Scanner?”

Comment: You're not going to get the characters as the user types. You can use next, get a string, then grab all of the characters from that string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just accept a char input

```
char temp keyboard.next().charAt(0);
charList.add(temp);
```

Always use the second, since you don't have any idea that user may enter String. Hence the second works for both.

Comment: next() always returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

us this 
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

char c = reader.nextChar();

You could take the first character from Scanner.next:

char c = reader.next().charAt(0);

To consume exactly one character you could use:

char c = reader.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

To consume strictly one character you could use:

char c = reader.next(".").charAt(0);

Comment: Scanner.nextChar doesn't exist.